# Android httpPost(URL) -> 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-status-code-403

I'm working on an Android App that sends data to a server (hosted in hostinger.es - for free to test the app) via new HttpPost(url); howevere, when I run the app in my cellphone, I always get the following answer in my logs:

```
09-03 15:24:40.916: response: 
<html>
<head>
<title>Error 403 - Forbidden</title>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.hostinger.co/error_404?" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My server code is php/mysql. I've changed the permissions in FileZilla of my folders and files .php but still getting same answer.

Code of my client for the request:

```
private static final String url = "http://yyy.esy.es/XXXX/process.php/senddata/";
// yyy subdomain in hostinger
// XXXX the folder where my php files are

protected void sendDataToServer(final TestData data) {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> keyValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    keyValuePairs.add(new KeyValuePair(Constant.FB_ID, data.getId()));

    ....
    ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);

    // Data that is to be sent
    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(keyValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, res);
```

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, if you really want to get good answers show the code that does te post. How do you want people to help you?

Comment: Done! I just added some code

Comment: Using Chrome browser developer tools, try to do a POST on that URL. Is there an error too?

Comment: @alpinescrambler I just tried a POST with http://www.hurl.it/ and it gave me a 200 status, no error there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. The problem is that hostinger does not allow remote connections to the Database in the free account, I didn't know that. To solve the problem, I've changed to other free web hosting provider and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you even though the following configuration was used to deal with certificates. However, I will try to provide you the simplified version with the mention that it is not tested. The one with certificates is tested and used so it works 
If you have any remarks just say it.

```
 //Method for getting the http client
 protected synchronized HttpClient getHttpClient() throws Exception {

    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params,
            HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, TIMEOUT);// (params,
                                                                // TIMEOUT);
    ConnPerRoute connPerRoute = new ConnPerRouteBean(MAX_CONN_PER_ROUTE);
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, connPerRoute);
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 20);
    // registers schemes for http
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme(Protocol.HTTP.toString(),
            PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    ClientConnectionManager connManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
            params, schemeRegistry);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager, params);
    return client;
}

//methods for executing the post. contentURL is the url that you use for post.  
protected HttpEntity executePostRequest(String contentURL, StringEntity body) {
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(contentURL);

    httpPost.setEntity(body);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HttpResponse response = executeHttpPost(httpPost);
    if (response != null) {
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }
    return entity;
}
 private synchronized HttpResponse executeHttpPost(HttpUriRequest httpPost) {
    Exception exception = null;
    try {
        HttpClient request = getHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = request.execute(httpPost);
        handleStatusCode(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error in executing the post request");
        if (e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "HttpResponseException");
            if (this.HTTP_STATUS_CODE == HTTP_STATUS_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                exception = new AuthenticationException(
                        "Unauthorized Exception");
            } else {
                exception = new HttpException(
                        "Http not authorized Exception");
            }
        } else if (this.HTTP_STATUS_CODE == HTTP_STATUS_BAD_REQUEST) {
            Log.e(TAG, "BAD Request. error in get execute");
            exception = new Exception("Bad Request");
        }
    }
    if (exception != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception." + exception.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try posting JSON style, and see what happens? For example:

```
 protected void sendDataToServer(final TestData data) { throws Exception 
 {

   Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put(Constant.FB_ID, data.getId()); // both strings???


 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


 HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);

 //convert the passed in parameters into JSON object
 JSONObject holder = getJsonObjectFromMap(params);


 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());


 httpost.setEntity(se);

 httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


 ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
 httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the web service is working, and in Android Emulator, You are getting 403 error.. Then I think you should put the User-Agent in your httpconnection code. Mostly you will get this kind of error in latest android 29/30

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
```